# Adjusting the Shield UI Chart refresh manner while displaying forex data

Tags: shieldui

While refreshing the Shield UI Chart there is some kind of flickering. Is is possible to adjust the chart’s settings, so that the new points appear more seamlessly? Here is the code that I use:

```
                    $("#ForexChart").shieldChart(
                        {

                            tooltipSettings: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            exportOptions:
                            {
                                image: false,
                                print: false
                            },
                            dataSeries: [
                                {
                                    seriesType: 'line',
                                    collectionAlias: 'Euro-US Dollar Crossrate',
                                    data: Fored_EUR_USD,
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things to be adjusted, as a matter of fact, so that the chart and data displayed look better.
Firtst I don’t see any settings for the X axis. You really need to set  is’t maximum. This is needed in order to have fixed ticks amount all the time:

```
axisX: {
 min: 0,
 max: 55
},
```

If max is not specified, each time a new point is added to the array the amount of ticks will increase, until we reach our array’s maximum desired size. As a matter of fact this behaviour will stop once we have all the points and start substituting the oldest one with the newest ones. However, especially with a slower refresh rate the chart will look annoying.

You also need to disable the animation explicitly:

```
 applyAnimation: {
  duration: 0
 },
```

and probably you may also want to remove the point marks, since just a line will look better.

Probably you may take use of this code:

```
seriesSettings: {
    line: {
        applyAnimation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        pointMark:{
            enabled: false
        }
    }
},
```